# Alignment problem if line breaks are used in listings

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings

I am using a monospace font and I want that all lines are horizontally aligned ("a" should be directly under "a"). How can I do this?

I have noticed that also the pagebreak symbol shifts the text. How can I draw a symbol e.g. in Tikz which has a maximum width of one character?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mathabx}


\lstset{
   breaklines=true,
   frame=lines,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,
   numbers=left,
   postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\drsh\space}},
   showlines=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
a = a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a ab a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the spacing of the math inside `\raisebox` in the `postbreak` option through `\mkern`:

```
postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\mkern-12mu\drsh\mkern-4mu}},
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mathabx}


\lstset{
   breaklines=true,
   frame=lines,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,
   numbers=left,
   postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\mkern-12mu\drsh\mkern-4mu}},
   showlines=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
a = a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a ab a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you need the symbol `\drsh` but you can't load `mathabx` in your document, you can simply "extract" the definition of the symbol from the package and insert it in your document, that is substitute the line

```
\usepackage{mathabx}
```

with

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\drsh}{3}{mathb}{"EB}
```

MWE that produces the same output as above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{mathabx}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\drsh}{3}{mathb}{"EB}

\lstset{
   breaklines=true,
   frame=lines,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,
   numbers=left,
   postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\mkern-12mu\drsh\mkern-4mu}},
   showlines=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
a = a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a ab a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx! Is it possible to draw the small arrow in Tikz because I am using Luatex and mathabx is not supported? I have tried \tikz ... in postbreak but I always get error messages. If I can use Tikz, do you know how I can find out the exact width of one monospace character?

Comment: @user4811 see the edit.

Comment: Thx, works great...